# Python: comparing two Counter objects with different keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, comparison

I have two strings that I want to word tokenize and then compare for differences

```
s1 = 'one two shmoo'
s2 = 'one one two'
```

My first thought was to turn them both into `collections.Counter` objects, wrap them in `pd.Series`, and subtract the difference.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
def counter_series(s):
    return pd.Series(Counter(s.split(' ')))

counter_series(s2) - counter_series(s1)
```

But the output shows that this difference doesn't provide a count for words that aren't present in both strings:

```
one      1.0
shmoo    NaN
two      0.0
dtype: float64
```

How can you include the missing counts? E.g. in the output above `shmoo` should also be 1. The solution doesn't have to use `pandas`.

Comment: The way you have it set up now you could get negative values, is that desired?

Comment: Wrapping `Counter` with `pd.Series`?!  You might as well use `pd.value_counts`

Comment: You could, and maybe it would be a bit faster, but that wouldn't solve the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sub` with `fill_value = 0`:

```
counter_series(s2).sub(counter_series(s1), fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
one     -1.0
shmoo    1.0
two      0.0
dtype: float64
```

And, you can add .abs() to get absolute value of differences:

```
counter_series(s2).sub(counter_series(s1), fill_value=0).abs()
```

Output:

```
one      1.0
shmoo    1.0
two      0.0
dtype: float64
```

However, I would use `value_counts` instead of import Counters from collections.

```
def count_series(x):
   s = pd.Series(x.split(' '))
   return s.value_counts()
```